# Browser asks for login when using port 443 for https (webdevelopment with node.js)

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, web-development-server

I am just creating a web application with node.js and wanted to introduce a SSL connection for my webpage (with self-signed certificates). The thing is, that as soon as I use the standard port 443 for the connection, the browser asks for a user and password.
I have nowhere definded a login with a user and password. And when I change the port to any other number, the site works as expected and I can open it.

I connect to the server with this command:

```
sslServer.listen(443, () => console.log('listening at port 443'));
```

I dont't know how to solve this problem as I am not that familiar with SSL etc. yet so maybe someone can help me out on this one?

Comment: Does your browser use a proxy for the connection to your server? (Check Settings > System.)

Comment: The settings opens the proxy-settings from windows. For the point "automatic proxy setup" it says, that it would "automatically recognize settings". All other options are disabled. Does this help?

Comment: Unless you are in a corporate network (which has some "automatic settings"), there is probably no proxy involved here. Sorry. Can you try `curl -v -X HEAD https://your.server:443` in the command line?

Comment: It says the following:

curl: (60) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

localhost:80 works fine.